# Where can I find datasets containing large phylogenetic networks?

Tags: phylogenetics, network, biological-networks

There are many datasets out there for phylogenetic trees, one can example can be found [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmicrobiol201648).

However, I couldn't find something for phylogenetic networks. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetic_network):

> A phylogenetic network or reticulation is any graph used to visualize
>   evolutionary relationships (either abstractly or explicitly)[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetic_network)
>   between nucleotide sequences, genes, chromosomes, genomes, or
>   species.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetic_network) They are employed when reticulation events such as
>   hybridization, horizontal gene transfer, recombination, or gene
>   duplication and loss are believed to be involved.

Of course a phylogenetic tree is a phylogenetic network, but phylogenetic networks can be thought of as rooted directed acyclic graphs, meaning that more complicated evolutionary structures can be captured.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I have an implementation of an algorithm that I would like to run on a phylogenetic network.

Comment: I handled your flag. This question was, however, not asked as a guest, as you have a user name and rep. So you cannot login under Jonathan?